# Preventing division by zero in the function 1/x with x $\geq$0 by adding a constant in the denominator allowed?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, limits

I want to use the function f(x) = 1/x with x $\geq$ 0.
However if x approaches 0, f(x) will go to infinity.
A solution is to add a constant to the denominator.
The values of x are mainly in the range of [0.1,2].
I don't want that the behavior of the function changes.
How do I choose this constant in a mathematically correct way?
Should it be a magnitude smaller, so for example 0.01?

Comment: Another solution is to define $f(x)$ piecewise, with one formula for $x > 0.1$ (or $x > k$ for any small positive $k$ that you choose) and another formula for smaller values of $x,$ chosen so that the function is continuous but doesn't tend to infinity near $x=0.$

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified what you mean by "behavior" in saying that you don't want the behavior of the function to change. Changing $f(x)=1/x$ to $f(x)=1/(x+c)$ for some constant $c>0$ essentially shifts the graph of the function to the left by $c$ units.  In doing so, you still preserve the strictly decreasing nature of the function while ensuring it is now well-defined for $x\geq 0$ with a vertical asymptote now at $x=-c$.

Comment: I mean by ''behavior'' that f(x) should have desirably very similar values before and after adding the constant c to the function as it describes a cost. The constant shouldn't change the f(x) drastically so that f(x) and with that the cost is not giving a distorted picture. In my case x represents a velocity.

Comment: @Math98 But adding any $c>0$ will necessarily change your function.  Among other things, $f(x)$ will no longer be unbounded for $x> 0$ no matter how small $c>0$ is, which is a major difference from the original function. You need to be more specific than saying "desirably very similar values."

Comment: I meant that if you have f(x)= 1/x and g(x) = 1/(1+c), that for x=0.7 f(x) = 1/0.7=1.43 and g(x) if c=1, is then g(x) = 1/(0.7+1) = 0.59. These are not very similar values, g(0.7) should be more like 1.3-1.4. That's what I mean.

Comment: @Math98 The smaller you make $c>0$, the less your function shifts to the left. Choosing $c=0.001$ gives $1/(0.7+0.001)\approx 1.427.$ Choosing $c=0.0001$ would get you even closer to $1/(0.7)$.  But there can be no "correct" or "best" $c$ because the problem "Choose $c>0$ to minimize $|\frac{1}{x+c}-\frac{1}{x}|$ at a given $x$" has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the input values are always greater than $0.1$ then the function $f(x) = 1/x$ will not misbehave on the domain that matters to you. If the values can sometimes be arbitrarily close to $0$ then  any $c >  0$ will make the the function $f(x) = 1/(x +c)$ well behaved for all positive $x$.

There is no "mathematically correct" way to choose a value of $c$. Use one that makes sense in your application.

Comment: As the values are mainly in the magnitude 0.1-1, it would make more sense to choose the c as 0.01 for example, so that the behavior of 1/x makes sense in the application i.e. the impact of the added constant is low on the term 1/x. I thought there would may be a rule of thumb.

Comment: Is it not always the best to choose c very low like 0.01 or 0.001 or even lower?

Comment: There is no mathematical "best" in this situation, nor is there any rule of thumb. Whatever $c$ you choose you could argue that $c/2$ is better. All you can do is use a $c$ that works in your context.

Comment: How do I know which c works in my context? By trial and error and see which one gives similar results to 1/x?

Comment: You know your context. We don't, so we can't tell you how to know what works. You know what "similar results to $1/x$" means. We don't. Either you have some reason to choose a particular $c$, or you experiment and settle on some value. I don't think I can be any clearer, so there's no point in your asking further in answer to this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a function that looks like the reciprocal function for large input but remains finite for small input. There are infinitely many such functions, but here is a simple one:

$f(x) = \dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, for each $x∈ℝ$.